# Find Symfony Widget Content File Location

Tags: php, symfony, widget

For the first time, i am working on Symfony widgets.

```
{% render "EducateToolsBundle:Shared:selectMenu" with {'entity': 'Stores'} %}
```

its Meaning is SharedController  -->selectMenuAction

```
{% form_theme form 'EducateToolsBundle:shared:_form_theme.html.twig' %}
```

What is the meaning of this.

From where i am getting the values to this form .?

Comment: I don't understand: which file location and content are you talking about?

Comment: What is the meaning of this line `{{ form_widget(theForm.id) }}` .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must look at `selectMenuAction()` method in the `Shared` controller. It is that function that set what template is used. if using the default Symfony coding standards it should be something like `selectMenu.html.twig` in a `Shared` sub folder in the `Resources/views` of the bundle.

Comment: `{% render "C2EducateToolsBundle:Shared:selectMenu" with {'entity': 'Stores'} %}`
its Meaning is SharedController  -->selectMenuAction 


`{% form_theme form 'C2EducateToolsBundle:shared:_form_theme.html.twig' %}`
What is the meaning of this.

From where i am getting the values to this form .?

Answer (score 1):

You should looks at the documentation first :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Because we won't teach you symfony here, it's very well explain in the documentation and it is a task too big for us.

In your case `theForm.id` is the field of the formType we want to displays.
If we want to display the `<input>` of an form of user lastname we would use

```
form_widget(userForm.lastname)
```

`form_widget` tells symfony to display only the widget (the ) of the id given.
if you want to have a label + input + the errors of the field you could use

```
form_row(userForm.lastname)
```

wich is **almost** equal to

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.lastname) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.lastname) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
</div>
```

(it depends of the form theme, but you should read the doc for the details ;) )

Comment: Your Answer is Clear to my, my Question is, in case of Select Options, how can i assign the the Values and how can i render the values in form using widget